# Prevent Resharper StyleCop Code Cleanup to create regions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting, stylecop, resharper-8.0

Upon code clean up (profile: StyleCop) it always creates regions for constructors, properties and so on...

```
#region Constructors and Destructors

public IpDiagnosticsService()
{
    // : base()
    // NOP. Required for serializer.
}

public IpDiagnosticsService(string applicationName, SPFarm farm) : base(applicationName, farm)
{
    // NOP
}

#endregion

#region Properties

// ...omitted.

#endregion
```

Awesome. I don't want that.
**How do it turn this off? Couldn't find any option for that.**

Answer (score 6):

Resharper depends on an XML file that defines the layout of the files. It can be found under Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Type Members Layout.

[image]

Remove the `<Group Region="*"/>` elements to remove the region creation. [More details about the file format can be found here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/04/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/).

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that and report back. At the very top there was an option to disable all regions iirc - that's why I didn't pay any further attention to the template.

Comment: That is a Resharper layout, I expected you wanted to retain all other StyleCop formatting  rules.